# My last line of Cypress code is not executed

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress

My last line of code is not executed and instead of that, the first line of code (that was visiting the page) is executed again, after which cypress tries to execute the remaining code which would automatically throw an error.

The last line of code is for selecting the mode of payment instead of which the page is redirected to the home page.

```
describe('Damensch', () => {
  it('Landing page', () => {

    cy.visit("https://dev1.damensch.com/")

  })
  it('Adding product to cart', () => {

    cy.xpath('//*[@id="menu-item-3531"]/a').click({ force: true })


    cy.xpath("(//span [@title='Limited Edition Box'])[2]").click()
    cy.xpath('//*[@id="bg-swatch-color"]/div[2]/div[3]/form/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]').click()


    cy.get(".qty-plus-btn").click()
    cy.contains('Add to cart').click()
    cy.xpath('//*[@id="primary-navigation"]/div/div/div/div/div[6]/ul/li/div/div/div[15]/p/a').click()  })

  it('Client details', () => {
    cy.get("#shipping_email").type("test11@gmail.com")
    cy.get("#shipping_phone").type("9087927738")
    cy.get("#shipping_name").type("Test Order")
    cy.get("#shipping_postcode").type("160022")
    cy.get("#shipping_address").type("221B Baker Street")
    cy.wait(3000)
    
    cy.get("#save-shipping-add").click() //after this line the browser is redirected to the homepage

    
  })
})
```

Comment: Hi. Could you assign cypress logs and the explicit error(if any) as well, please? Also, I would recommend to change the structure of your test, e.g. use hooks for your visit command, or wrap the whole scenario in one block, so you will avoid domino effect in case the first test is failing

Answer (score 1):

This happens, because your test successfully  performs the last click and - because you have no assertion to end the test - it assumes the case is finished so it redirects to the default page.

Putting [assertions](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html) as an end to the test should solve your problem and it is not a good practice to finish a test automation process without an assertion.

Comment: Even if i try to give any other command line after the last click it still redirects to the source page and then tries executing them @Rosen Mihaylov

Comment: Even if that`s an assertion, not any command? It is important to be an assertion

Comment: I see it in my tests to happen when there are some processes left unfinished on the page but the test had finished and My solution was to make a better assertions that happen after i`m sure the page has finished rendering